# ¿Cómo puedo obtener mediante "js" el email y el nombre de usuario en github del archivo de configuración "~/.gitconfig"?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, github

¿Cómo puedo obtener mediante "js" el email y el nombre de usuario en github?
Mediante el archivo de configuración "~/.gitconfig", que es el que almacena user.name y user.email.

Comment: Hola @María_. ¿Estás siguiendo tu pregunta?

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo. Por ejemplo, mediante la interface `readline` puedes leer línea por línea un `stream` de lectura generado por `fs`. Determinar en qué línea empieza el bloque `[user]` y leer las líneas posteriores extayendo el `name` y el `email`.

```
const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');


function processGitFile(file, cb) {
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(file)
  });

  let insideUserBlock = false;
  const data = {};
  rl.on('line', (line) => {
    if(data.name && data.email) {
      insideUserBlock = false;
      rl.close();
    }
    // está en el bloque [user]
    if(insideUserBlock) {
      const parts = line.split('=');
      // substring(1) elimina el espacio del primer caracter
      if(line.indexOf('name') !== -1) {
        data.name = parts[1].substring(1);
      } else if(line.indexOf('email') !== -1) {
        data.email = parts[1].substring(1);
      }
    }
    if(line.indexOf('[user]') !== -1) {
      insideUserBlock = true;
    }
  });
  rl.on('close', () => cb(data));
}
```

Lo usarías así:

```
processGitFile('./.gitconfig', userData => (
  // hacer algo
));
```

---

La ventaja de este método es que no importa en dónde está situado `[user]`, igual funcionará. Por otro lado, son substring es más complicado hacerlo porque éste método confía en que `[user]` siempre estará luego o antes de determinado bloque.

Ejemplo de resultado:

```
{ name: 'Mitsu Gami', email: 'idontknow@aaa.xyz' }
```